# How to show one to many relationship between two tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables A and B.

A table contain

```
postid,postname,CategoryURl
```

and

B table contain

```
postid,CategoryImageURL
```

For one postid there are multiple CategoryImageURL assigned.I want to display that CategoryImageURL in Table A but for one postid there should be CategoryImageURL1,CategoryImageURL2 should be like that one.

I want to achieve one to many relationship for one postid then what logic should be return in sql function??

Comment: Voted down - please consider changing the title. Title should contain brief explanation of your problem and not "hello i am new..."

Comment: You are new to asp.net but this question is not related to that.

Comment: This belongs to presentation level, pls deal with it there.

Answer (score 1):

In my eyes it seems that you want to display all related CategoryImageURLs of the second table in one line with a separator in this case the comma? 
Then you will need a recursive operation there. Maybe a CTE (Common Table Expression) does the trick. See below. I have added another key to the second table, to be able to check, if all rows of the second table have been processed for the corresponding row in the first table.

Maybe this helps:

```
with a_cte (post_id, url_id, name, list, rrank) as 
(
    select
        a.post_id
        , b.url_id
        , a.name
        , cast(b.urln + ', ' as nvarchar(100)) as list
        , 0 as rrank
    from 
        dbo.a
    join dbo.b  
        on a.post_id = b.post_id
union all
    select
        c.post_id 
        , a1.url_id
        , c.name
        , cast(c.list + case when rrank = 0  then '' else ', ' end + a1.urln as nvarchar(100))
        , c.rrank + 1
    from a_cte c
    join (  select 
                b.post_id
                , b.url_id
                , a.name
                , b.urln
            from dbo.a
            join dbo.b
            on a.post_id = b.post_id
                   ) a1
    on c.post_id = a1.post_id
    and c.url_id < a1.url_id -- ==> take care, that there is no endless loop
)
select d.name, d.list
from
    (
    select name, list, rank() over (partition by post_id order by rrank desc)
    from a_cte
    ) d (name, list, rank)
where rank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the wrong sort of question. This is about normalization.

As it stands, you have a redundancy? Where each postname and categoryURL is represented by an ID field.

For whatever reason, the tables separated CategoryImageUrl into its own table and linked this to each set of postname and categoryURL.

If the relation is actually one id to each postname, then you can denormalize the table by adding the column CategoryImageUrl to your first table.

Postid, postname, CategoryURL, CategoryImageUrl

Or if you wish to keep the normalization, combine like fields into their own table like so:

```
--TableA:
Postid, postname, <any other field dependent on postname >
--TableA
Postid, CategoryURL, CategoryImageUrl
```

Now this groups CategoryURL together but uses a redundancy of having multiple CategoryURL to exist. However, Postid has only one CategoryUrl.

To remove this redundancy in our table, we could use a `Star Schema` strategy like this:

```
-- Post Table
Postid, postname

-- Category table
CategoryID, CategoryURL, <any other info dependent only on CategoryURL>

-- Fact Table
Postid, CategoryID, CategoryImageURL
```

DISCLAIMER: Naturally I assumed aspects of your data and might be off. However, the strategy of normalization is still the same.

Also, remember that **SQL is relational and deals with sets of data. Inheritance is incompatible to the relational set theory**. Every table can be queried forwards and backwards much the way every page and chapter in a book is treated as part of the book. At no point would we see a chapter independent of a book.